# makeglossaries doesn't work

Tags: glossaries

I'm trying to run makeglossaries in TexStudio (and TexMaker). It seems that this doesn't have any effect on the glossary printed. This problem persisted after switching from windows to linux

I run (which is supposed to do all the work I need :D):

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | makeglossaries % | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | bibtex %.aux | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | txs:///view
```

on something like that:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
BCOR=10mm,
listof=totoc,
bibliography=totoc
]
{scrbook} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage[]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bookmarksopenlevel=section]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc, xindy, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} %enables diagram painting
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{float}%enables force position for images
\loadglsentries[main]{07_glossary/glossary.tex}  %load glossary file    

% Bibliography
\bibliographystyle{acm}


% Glossary
\makeglossaries
\setglossarystyle{list}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{british}

...


\twocolumn
\printglossaries

...

\end{document}
```

The first time I run my custom "makeglossaries" it build me a glossary with content, but since then it won't include any changes.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Greetings
hornhaut

EDIT:

In 07_glossary/glossary.tex there are entries like:

```
\newglossaryentry{sdk}{
    type=\acronymtype, 
    name={SDK},
    first={Software Development Kit (SDK)},
    description={A Software Development Kit consists out of tools and applications needed to enable functions of a certain type of software},
    plural={SDKs},
    firstplural={Software Development Kits (SDKs)}
    }
```

The entries are all the same (I always copied this entry end changed name, description, sometimes removed plural and firstplural and double checked if I've used the commas correctly)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your document is not compilable, since the entries in `07_glossary/glossary.tex` are unavailable to users here

Comment: After you made the changes, did the rerun of `makeglossaries` display any error messages? Are there any messages in the `.glg` file? Is the time stamp on the `.gls` file more recent than the time stamp on the `.glo` file? Does the `.glo` file contain the changes that you made? (Please can you trim down your example code to a proper [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). There's a lot of code there that's not relevant.)

Comment: Do you actually use any of the entries in the document? Please make your code both more minimal (as Nicola Talbot asked) and compilable so that it **reproduces the problem**. Otherwise, people are just whistling in the dark!

Comment: OK,

I printed my glossary and double checked it again. Actually I found a missing comma :/

Sorry for the unnecessary question.

At least now I know how to phrase the question. Wasn't aware that you are compiling the code, as in e.g. stackoverflow it usually is sufficient to paste the code where I assume that the error might be...

I promise improvement :)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a user error in input (missing comma)

Comment: @hornhaut Although TeX is Turing complete, it's very different from other languages. Syntax can be changed on the fly, subtle changes (such as the order of loading packages) can have a major effect, so code fragments don't usually help much as the error could be caused by something earlier in the document.